# How to write unit test for a private void method in which other private method is being called?

Tags: java, junit

```
private void ConvertString(ABC object) 
{
    String head = "";
    String tail="string_tail";
    if(!tail.isEmpty()) 
    {
        String converter = new StringConvert();
        head = converter.convert(tail, TYPE1);
        setHeadToTail(head,object);
    }
}

private void setHeadToTail(String head, ABC object) 
{
    List<Mixture> values=object.getValues();
    if (values!=null) 
    {
        for (Mixture Values1 : values) 
        {
            if (Values1 instanceof NumMixture) 
            {
                ((NumMixture) Values1 ).setTail(head);
            }
        }
     }
```

}

I want to write unit test for `ConvertString` method to check weather the value 'head' converted is equal to the value 'head' being passed in `setHeadToTail()`.
Can anyone help in this?

```
@Test
public void test_ConvertedValue() throws Exception {

    ABC obj1=methodToSetSomeValues();
    Method method=Project.class.getDeclaredMethod("ConvertString", ABC.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(new Project(), obj1);
    String expectedVal= "1234";

    ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor=ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

    verifyPrivate(new Project()).invoke("setHeadToTail", argumentCaptor.capture(), obj1);
    assertEquals(expectedVal,argumentCaptor.getValue());


}
```

In this test case I want to check the value of 'head' converted is equal to parameter passed in `setHeadToTail()` i.e. head but this is not working.

Comment: What framework are you using for testing?

Comment: That simply does not matter. Your test is supposed to test the public API of your class, private methods do not matter. You need to properly test whoever calls `ConvertString` or extract it into a `Helper` class and mock an instance of it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question when I first started out. Basically, you can view a `private` method as just code as if it wasn't in a method at all; it's just there to make your code more readable or to remove boilerplate. So if you want to test the functionality, you need to test the method which is calling it.

```
public void someMethod() { // test this
    // some code
    privateMethod();
    // some more code
}

private void privateMethod() {
    // some code
}
```

When unit testing `someMethod()`, act as if the contents of `privateMethod()` are not in any method at all.

edit: In your case, it doesn't matter how many nested `private` methods you have, test the non-private method calling them all as if it were 1 large block of code.